# SQL Developer - Commented fields are shown as the field name

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using SQL Developer Version 19.2.1.247.

I have this simple code:

```
SELECT 1
--      ,iasdhoal
--      ,ifgdgo
--      ,uidfydiofjd
      ,COUNT(1)
  FROM dual
;
```

The result shows the commented fields as the field name of the "1", like this:
[image]

The result I want should be like this (Version 3.2.20.10):
[image]

I tried to look for it on the settings related to "alias", "column", or "field". I tried unchecking the "Generate Comlumn/Table aliases automatically" under Code Editor: Completion Insight, but that's not it. I know it's in the settings somewhere, I just don't know what it's called.

Answer (score 0):

You'd get the same result in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> SELECT 1
  2  --      ,iasdhoal
  3  --      ,ifgdgo
  4  --      ,uidfydiofjd
  5        ,COUNT(1)
  6    FROM dual
  7  ;

1--,IASDHOAL--,IFGDGO--,UIDFYDIOFJD   COUNT(1)
----------------------------------- ----------
                                  1          1
```

One option is to **relocate comma**:

```
SQL> SELECT 1,                  --> put it here
  2  --      ,iasdhoal
  3  --      ,ifgdgo
  4  --      ,uidfydiofjd
  5        COUNT(1)             --> remove it from here
  6    FROM dual
  7  ;

         1   COUNT(1)
---------- ----------
         1          1

SQL>
```

Alternatively, you could provide **alias** for `1` you selected:

```
SQL> SELECT 1 "1"
  2  --      ,iasdhoal
  3  --      ,ifgdgo
  4  --      ,uidfydiofjd
  5        ,COUNT(1)              --> comma remained here
  6    FROM dual
  7  ;

         1   COUNT(1)
---------- ----------
         1          1

SQL>
```